# How do I link JS and CSS in a different directory to my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My files are in entirely separate folders. I'm attempting to call CSS and JS files from a different path. Example below:

```
mainDirectory\internal\scripts\main.js
mainDirectory\internal\styles\main.css
mainDirectory\internal\pages\homePage.html -- (main page file)
```

I want to do this without libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../folderThree\test.css">
    <script src="../folderTwo/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was able to determine that I made a syntax mistake here, as I'm used to a different system. Turns out that all I needed `../` and to swap my slashes from back to forward.